# Opening Same Table Twice In Update

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to normalise a large dataset, I've built a table with all the relationships, called App(earances). Then I loop through another table to build a temp table which contains the duplicates, with MasterID being the one I want to keep.

The data in the duplicate table looks like this:
[image]

I then try to update the app table, swapping any duplicate id's for the corresponding master id, but I'm getting the Error: Can't reopen table: 'd'.

Here is the code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Duplicates;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Duplicates (
    MasterID    int NOT NULL,
    DuplicateID int NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Duplicates(MasterID, DuplicateID)
SELECT      p1.PlayerID as MasterID, p2.PlayerID as DuplicateID
FROM        Player p1
LEFT JOIN   Player p2   on p1.Name = p2.Name
WHERE       p1.name     = p2.name
AND         p1.PlayerID < p2.PlayerID
ORDER BY    p1.PlayerID;

UPDATE  app a
SET     a.PlayerID =    ( SELECT d.MasterID FROM Duplicates d WHERE a.PlayerID = d.DuplicateID LIMIT 1 )
WHERE   a.PlayerID in (SELECT d.DuplicateID FROM Duplicates d);

DELETE  Player p
WHERE   PlayerID = ( SELECT d.DuplicateID FROM Duplicates d )
DROP TABLE Duplicates;
```

The problem is with the update query, I've put the other queries in so you can get a better idea of what's going on, I think a CTE would be better here but I don't know how I could do it. I'm running this in MYSQL at the moment but I could use another SQL variant.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `join`:

```
UPDATE app a JOIN
       Duplicates d
       ON a.PlayerID = d.DuplicateID       
    SET a.PlayerID =  d.MasterID;
```

`a` will get set from an arbitrary row in `d`, if there are multiple matches in `d` for a given `a`.

I suppose it is not a great idea to have multiple possible rows update a single row, so you could aggregate before the `join`:

```
UPDATE app a JOIN
       (SELECT d.DuplicateID, MAX(d.MasterId) as MasterId
        FROM Duplicates d
        GROUP BY d.DuplicateID
       ) d
       ON a.PlayerID = d.DuplicateID       
    SET a.PlayerID =  d.MasterID;
```

Comment: that hasn't worked, for example PlayerID 767 still exists in the app table, it should have been replaced with 1

Comment: @CraigHarley . . . That is very curious.  I would expect both to work.